Android - TextInputEditText text being spelled inverted
I have a TextInputEditText in my fragment and whenever I type a text, it is being spelled inverted. SO if I try and type "Leonardo", it will be spelled "odranoeL". The cursor is being positioned on the start of the last letter inputted and the next letter is put on the left side of the last one.
This is my XML:
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/match_edit_education_input_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/match_edit_profession_input_layout">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/match_edit_education_input"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:hint="@string/education_mandatory"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

I try to isolate it on another project, but the I can't replicate the problem.

Need more code. I suspect there is some TextWatcher that resets the cursor position on every change.

@jokuskay That was precisely the problem. Do I close this or you want to post an answer? I think you should post an answer, or else if anyone have a similar question, they might find a solution.

I suspect there is some TextWatcher that resets the cursor position on every change.
